# cumulative secrets

Tags: protocol-design, authentication, keys, protocol-analysis

Imagine a server with an authentication scheme that utilizes an element of randomness in new sessions (i.e. one that uses the secure remote password protocol).

At the end of a successful authentication, when session keys are being derived (via hkdf), suppose a "history key" was derived as well.

In the first interaction, during an initial establishment of a secret this history key is then hashed (if necessary?) and dumped to a file. The history key is then discarded.

When further secret history keys are generated in future sessions, they are also hashed and xor'd (or combined however) with the history file.

The history file becomes a token, and on login a hash of it is presented as in addition to the regular password verification process. The hash proves possession/knowledge of the cumulative history of secrets between the client/server so far.

An idea is that the history could also be used during key derivation to establish more secure keys then those based on the secret established by the asymmetric crypto alone.

It's easy for me to try and find potential upsides. Are there any obvious flaws to the idea? The one downside I am immediately aware of is the issue of key management with the history file.

Assuming the idea isn't fundamentally flawed: Are there any schemes that have already implemented such a feature?